# Efficient way to do multiple logical operations

Tags: r, performance

Suppose that I have three vectors of the same length

```
vec1 <- c(1,2,3,10)
vec2 <- c(1,4,5,8)
vec3 <- c("==","<=",">=","==")
```

I want to compare vec1[x] with vec2[x] using the operator in vec3[x], to check if all are true. My current solution is the following

```
vec1 <- c(1,2,3,10)
vec2 <- c(1,4,5,8)
vec3 <- c("==","<=",">=","==")

result <- TRUE

for (i in 1:4){
  if (vec3[i] == "=="){
    if (! vec1[i] == vec2[i]) {
      result <- FALSE
      break
    } 
  } else if (vec3[i] == "<=") {
    if (! vec1[i] <= vec2[i]) {
      result <- FALSE
      break
    } 
  } else if (vec3[i] == ">=") {
    if (! vec1[i] >= vec2[i]) {
      result <- FALSE
      break
    }
  }
}

print(result)
```

output is

```
[1] FALSE
```

It works but it's slow if vectors are larger and you have to do many. Is there a better way to do it?
The vectors are sorted in such a way that the comparisons that are most likely to return FALSE come first.
I'll add that in practice the vectors are of length 28. vec2 and vec3 are constant and vec1 is variable.

Comment: These are vectorized operations you can do `vec1 == vec2`

Comment: and you can wrap with `any`

Answer (score 1):

This could be reduced to

```
f1 <- function(v1, v2, oper) {

  all(Reduce(`&`, lapply(oper, function(op) match.fun(op)(v1, v2))))

 }

f1(vec1, vec2, vec3)
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `eval` + `call` like this

```
all(mapply(function(op, a, b) eval(call(op, a, b)), vec3, vec1, vec2))
```

or `Vectorize` + `do.call`

```
all(Vectorize(do.call)(vec3, apply(cbind(vec1, vec2), 1, as.list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One `purrr` option could be:

```
all(pmap_lgl(list(vec1, vec2, vec3), ~ exec(..3, ..1, ..2)))

[1] FALSE
```